# Cannot Assign Variable to a Variable in Update Statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

In my Stored Procedure i'm passing column names and values as a text, substring them using substring_index and i'm trying to assign them like in the below code. But MySQL prompts me a syntax error.

How can I resolve this?

```
var1, var2 varchar(50);
set @var1 = substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(query,',',1),',',1),'=',1);
set @var2 = substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(query,',',1),',',1),'=',-1);
```

gives an syntax error here

```
update device
set @var1=@var2 
where dv_id=deviceId;

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL  server version for the right syntax to use near '@var1=@var2
where dv_id=deviceId;
-- prepare stmt1 from @s;
-- execute stmt1 usi' at line 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that this:

```
set @var1 = @var2
```

isn't a value SET clause for an UPDATE. MySQL won't evaluate your variables to get at the expressions they contain. However, you can use [PREPARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/prepare.html) and [EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execute.html) to build and execute the SQL dynamically. Something like this:

```
set @var1   = substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(query,',',1),',',1),'=',1);
set @var2   = substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(query,',',1),',',1),'=',-1);
set @update = concat('update device set ', @var1, ' = ', @var2, ' where dv_id = deviceId');
prepare stmt from @update;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```